# Count number of values between two numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I am finding with some formulas for my web application. I need a formula that counts the number of values between two number, e.g. there are four numbers (3,4,5,6) between 2 and 7

Comment: this problem just might be NP-complete.  i hope you have enough computing power to tackle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

larger - smaller - 1. If you don't count the larger and the smaller (like your example).

If the numbers are $n, n+1, \dots, n+k , n+k+1$, the numbers you want are $n+1, n+2, \dots, n+k$, which are $k$ in number = $n+k+1 - n - 1$ = larger - smaller - 1.

Comment: @Cudos: and *if* your quantities are both integers, and you include *all* integers between the two in your count, and *only* integers...

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, that was the assumption made based on the example.

Comment: Not faulting you; I always have to hit my students over the head with the fact that "numbers" doesn't mean "integers and only integers" unless one says so explicitly.

Comment: @Arturo: Agree with that :-)

Answer (score 4):

The number between $a,b$ is $(a<b)$

- Including $a,b$ them self: $b-a+1$
- Excluding $a,b$ :$b-a-1$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ The problem admits an obvious shift **symmetry**, e.g. considering the example that you gave, a shift of $-2\:$ to $[3, 6]$ yields $[1,4]$, which clearly has $4$ integers. Innate symmetries should always be investigated since they may play a key role in simplifying the search for a solution. Moreover, it's best to learn these symmetry-based problem solving techniques for simple problems like this, since you may not be able to see the forest for the trees in much more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger number minus the smaller number minus 1.
Or if $b$ is the bigger number, $s$ the smaller. We have:
$b - s - 1$